# Extract numeric values from strings and split them according to original order

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I'm trying to to extract all numeric values from a string-column in R that contains numeric and non-numeric values. My goal is to keep original order by replacing all accumulations of non-numeric values with commas.

My example data:

```
name <- c("./Stimuli\49stim_9_with_14_vs_23_mix2.png", "./Stimuli\54stim_14_with_15_vs_21_mix2.png", "./Stimuli\75stim_15_with_18_vs_26_incongruent.png")
```

My expected outcome:

```
expectedpoutcome <- c("49, 9, 14, 23, 2", "54, 14, 15, 21, 2", "75, 15, 18, 26")
```

The closest I could get:

```
library(stringr)

myoutcome <- name %>% str_match_all("[0-9]+") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric
```

The problem with that list is that the information regarding which original string the numbers were from gets lost.

Comment: You say you’ve tried using regex. **Show us your attempt**, please. Then we can offer specific corrections. Also, where do these backslashes in the file names come from? They’re almost certainly not supposed to be there.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have edited the post and removed regex, because it was the wrong term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is correct. The issue, rather, is the code that comes after it: you are flattening the list (and thus losing the correspondence between numbers and original string), and then you’re converting the output to numbers, even though you indicated that you want to obtain a *string*.

So, start by removing the `%>% unlist %>% as.numeric` steps.

Next, there’s a neat trick to merge a list of strings into a single, comma-separated string: `toString`. So apply that over your list of results:

```
name %>% stringr::str_match_all("[0-9]+") %>% sapply(toString)
```

And there we have it.

Additionally you can simplify the regular expression: `\d` is identical to `[0-9]`; giving us:

```
name %>% stringr::str_match_all("\\d+") %>% sapply(toString)
```

And, lastly, your “expected outcome” is plain wrong, because you’re misinterpreting the meaning of backslash escape sequences in the string. [Read the documentation on string escape sequences](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html).

Alternatively, instead of matching all digits you can do the opposite: match everything that’s *not* a digit, and replace such runs by `', '`. However, then you’ll afterwards need to remove leading and trailing commas:

```
trimws(gsub('\\D+', ', ', name), whitespace = ', ')
```

Comment: Danke, and you're correct, saving the outcome in a string was the wrong goal and also not beneficial to my final goal, which was to "expand" the numbers to different columns, in a way that there'd be a column for the first numbers, a second column for the second an so on... Could you help me with that?

Comment: @psyph If the count of numbers is the same in every string you can replace `sapply(toString)` in the above with `lapply(as.vector) %>% {do.call(rbind.data.frame, .)}`. Then you just need to sanitise the autogenerated column names. *Normally* the ugly `{do.call(rbind.data.frame, .)}` bit at the end could just be replaced by `bind_rows` from dplyr, but for some reason this doesn’t work with my installed version of dplyr, presumably due to a bug.

Comment: Sadly, some strings contain four numbers and some five. Is there no way to create a fifth column and get NA for all values strings that have 4 numbers?

Comment: But if you're not interested in it for the sake of it, I can already use the solution you just provided. So thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse solution is this:

```
name %>% str_extract_all("\\d+") %>% map_chr(paste, collapse = ", ")
```

This does not produce the output you showed, the reason is that you are supplying escaped characters  which end up not being numbers at all.
R won't know what was supplied as is and what was supplied via an escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, we can extract all the numeric values using `gregexpr` and `regmatches` and change them to comma-separated string using `toString`.

```
sapply(regmatches(name, gregexpr("[0-9]+", name)), toString)
#[1] "49, 9, 14, 23, 2" "14, 15, 21, 2"    "75, 15, 18, 26"
```